# Can I use F# in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2012

Microsoft released F# tools for *Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web*, but I'm using *Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop*. I read that Microsoft had no plans to support the desktop version.

Is there still a way to use F# in *Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop*? Is it possible to somehow invoke the F# compiler that ships with the F# tools for *Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web*?

Comment: Short answer: not really. But what are you ultimately trying to accomplish? Are you trying to avoid having two VS Express versions installed? If not, then the outputs of one can easily be leveraged from the other. Of course, testing/debugging is somewhat more delineated... but that's not necessarily a bad thing. Also, you can build F# exe's from VS Express Web -- just change the project output type.

Comment: It's quite sad that they removed Shell support...

Comment: It's quite sad that they never did a Visual F# Express...

Comment: It's quite sad that they never did a single Visual Studio Express that just supported all languages at once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there still a way to use F# in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop?

No. Of the free editions, F# 3.0 only works with Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web.

> Is it possible to somehow invoke the F# compiler that ships with the F# tools for Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web?

Not AFAIK.

Comment: FWIW, it turns out that if you install F# Tools for Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web on a machine that doesn't have VS 2012 installed, it works, and you get the command-line compiler and FSharp.Core. Handy for a build server. Web Platform Installer wants to install VS and lots of other stuff, but you can just use the [Direct Download Link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=261286) in the prerequisites window.

Comment: It seems possible to open VSE Windows Desktop solutions in VSE Web and use that. I'm not writing GUI applications anyway, and this works with console applications, so it's fine.